# Where to find date & time of currently running SQL agent job STEP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I want to query a view or table for the currently running SQL agent job **steps** and when did they start.

I've tried queries below but it gives me JOB datetime rather then step datetime.

```
select top 100 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
select top 100 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobstepslogs
select top 100 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory 
exec master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1  , garbage -- gives me currently running job step
```

Screen Shot of desired values below from SQL Activity Monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id as JobId,
    j.name AS JobName,
    ja.start_execution_date as StartDn,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS CurrentStepId
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON ja.job_id = js.job_id AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syssessions r ON r.session_id = ja.session_id
WHERE start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

You might check this [article](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/05/a-t-sql-query-to-get-current-job-activity/) for further information

hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Hadi. The query returns date for job start time and or 1st step. I want to query when either of the steps started/finished.

Comment: remove the `stop_execution_date is null` it should give you all the history

Comment: I have tried that as well but it gives me Job's datetime for some historic executions.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hank Freeman */
use master
go
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date, 
    --2019-06-10 18:54:31.000
    getdate() as 'NOW',
    '0'+Cast(Datepart(hh,(getdate() -  ja.start_execution_date)) as char(2)) + ':' +
    Cast(Datepart(n,(getdate() -  ja.start_execution_date))  as char(2)) + ':'  +
    '0'+Cast(Datepart(ss,(getdate() -  ja.start_execution_date)) as char(2))    as 'Duration',
    Cast(DATEDIFF(n,ja.start_execution_date,getdate())  as char(5))     as 'Duration_Mins',
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS cur_exec_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 session_id 
    FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions 
    ORDER BY session_id DESC
    )
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null
order by 2
;
```